# How Applet talk to Web server

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc, applet

I am going to build web application in Java (JSP). In my web application ;JApplet will communicate with the database that is on other place(Remote Database).
My question is that how applet can take and give the data from the  database.
I am Using MYSQL database.
Can I use JDBC for that ?If so then how?

Answer (score 1):

Unsigned applets must follow the same origin policy, hence the applet will only be able to talk with the server from where it was downloaded. For this case it may work, assuming you bundle JDBC driver somehow (like moving driver classes into applet jar, or trying to use multiple jars in the same applet).

However if you want to deploy the application more widely, it may be better to use text based communication (XML or JSON) on the server port 80. JDBC port may be blocked by various firewalls.

As the alternative to the applet technology, you may also look into Google Web Toolkit. It is the same Java (just toolkit compiles to JavaScript) and you should feel at home, but it is easier to deploy reliably. GWT provides callbacks to pass the data to and from the server.

Comment: *"Google Web Toolkit. ..it is easier to deploy reliably."*  ..At places *outside* of Google?  Does GWT make code that is portable to other servers?

Comment: Yes, you can put it into any Java - capable server definitely. I run it on my server that is not linked with Google in any way. It only needs something like Tomcat or Jetty to run. A Google-bound Google App Engine (GAE) can optionally be used but not required.

Comment: Sir is the Applet secure as compared to HTML page .If Applet talking with web server and data base server?

Answer (score 0):

what you exactly wanted to do is run to your applet inside your web container for that you study the architecture of J2EE web container that how it run applet container.you can check on the oracle site link :  about j2EE containers. for the architecture you can view this :http://tekmarathon.files.wordpress.com/2012/10/j2ee_component_diagram.png

Comment: thanks for your answering.
I am just want that how applet can communicate with the database.
Lets consider when applet download on the client machine then this applet will interact with database server using HTTP protocol.
is JDBC enough to to make applet can talk to the database.
Hope you got the Idea...

Comment: and my 2nd question is Applet  good approach for to  embed this in the web application?
or I use HTML or Java Script instead Applet?

Comment: applet is part of javaSE whereas you wanted to embed it in jsp which is part of javaEE tech, what i understood is you want to take some input from the user and use that to interact with the database for that you can use servlets-jsp.As applet will be run on client side machine .JDBC does not care about from where you are creating connection it just fetches the result and return to you rest is your task how you use either in your web application or in your client side application.and for your second question use HTML/jsp that will be easy for that to interact with the web application

Comment: JDBC does not care but it uses javaSE classes like Socket to connect the database. These classes are under control of the security manager that will enforce same origin policy for sandboxed applets.